# Bigquery Simba ODBC autocommit

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using Microstrategy to connect to Google Bigquery. The Microstrategy report is issuing `Insert` statements to bigquery which are failing with the following error message:

```
Push Auto Commit failed. 
Error type: Odbc error. Odbc operation attempted: SQLSetConnectOption. Option: SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT. [HYC00:11470: on SQLHANDLE] [MicroStrategy][ODBC] (11470) Transactions are not supported.
```

Comment: Can you please give some code that you use and try to explain the question more.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your simba odbc driver settings and version.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible options on how to solve this issue:

**Option 1**

Per Simba ODBC release notes which are found in this [link](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/odbc/release-notes.txt) you need to make sure you are using version 2.1.16 and that you have enabled the **IgnoreTransactions** configuration option

> [GAUSS-634] Ignoring Transaction Data
>
> The driver can now be configured to ignore transaction data in query results. To do this, enable the IgnoreTransactions configuration option.
>      For details, see the Installation and Configuration Guide.

Another interesting option in this version

> [GAUSS-663] Support for MERGE
>
> The driver now supports MERGE as a DML statement.

Check the Advanced Options in the ODBC SIMBA configuration menu

[image]

**Option 2**

If you are connected to Microstrategy via Linked connection you need to follow the instructions in Simba [FAQ page](https://www.simba.com/resources/drivers/faq/google-bigquery/)

> Insert, Update, and Delete fail with an error saying the Linked Server doesn’t support the required transaction interfaces.
>   Linked Server does not use ODBC natively, it uses OLE DB and to talk to ODBC it uses the Microsoft OLE DB to ODBC bridge. This is where the problem arises. You can work around this by disabling transactions for DML queries with the provider. Delete the linked server connection to the data source, then open the Linked Server Providers and right click on the MDASQL one. Select the “Non-transacted updates” and then recreate the linked server and try again.

Comment: Hi Tamir, Since the ODBC is configured in the windows system, the IgnoreTransactions option is not exposed. Please refer to page 65 in the following document :https://docs.rstudio.com/drivers/1.6/pdf/Simba%20ODBC%20Driver%20for%20Google%20BigQuery%20Install%20and%20Configuration%20Guide.pdf  . So do we need to give this option in the ODBC.ini file located in the C:\Windows directory ?

Comment: I Typically use the ODBC window modal but maybe also the .ini file might help you, Anyway I put more information in my answer which I believe can help you solve your problem.

Comment: @ThirumalaiMuthuPalani, Any feedback on this?

Comment: Hi Tamir. We applied IgnoreTransactions in the ODBC file as well as in Registry as it is a windows server. But it did not work. Thanks.

Comment: By default auto-commit is on, the ODBC driver turns off auto-commit and is trying to perform insertion from the reporting tool (Microstrategy) which is not working. I contacted Microstrategy technical support team and they said that it is a default behaviour which cannot be changed.

Comment: We have an option in Microstrategy to provide the option "ignoreTransactions" and we were able to get past the error. Thanks Tamir.

Answer (score 0):

First, download and configure the latest ODBC driver from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers):

Next - use the connection like this (note the IgnoreTransactions parameter):

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery};OAuthMechanism=0;Catalog=<projectID>;KeyFilePath=<path to json credentials>;Email=<email of service account>;IgnoreTransactions=1')

qry = 'select * from <path to your table>'
data = pd.read_sql(qry,conn)
```